# c# - Form does not contain a definition for btnCalc_Click and no method extension

Tags: c#, winforms

I am wanting to put Event KeyDown for when the user. Click on one button of the KeyBoard, and it will do something.

But It's not working, it says that my Form does not contain a definition for the **button(btnCalc_Click)** and **no method extension**.

My code is :

```
  private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (btnLimpar.Enabled)
                {  
                    btnLimpar.PerformClick();
                }
                else
                {  
                    this.btnLimpar_Click(null, new EventArgs());
                }
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.End)
            {
                if (btnCalcular.Enabled)
                {
                    btnCalcular.PerformClick();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.btnCalcular_Click(null, new EventArgs());
                }

            }

        }
```

It get's wrong in the code : `this.btnCalcular_Click(null, new EventArgs());`

> > **Error:** FormularioHospital.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'btnCalcular_Click' and no extension method 'btnCalcular_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'FormularioHospital.Form1' could be found.
> >     `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Go to designer and simply double click on your button. it will create that method for you.

**Option 2:**

Create this method, then using designer, assign that method to click event of your button.

```
private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // codes that you want execute when your button clicked
}
```

Comment: Thanks your Options really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

### **First Option**

1. You should create a button `btnCalcular`
2. Double Click on the Button

It will create the necessary procedure for you.

### **Second option**

1. You can create a button `btnCalcular`

and Paste this code on your code behind

```
private void btnCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping,your Options too,helped me.